# How to force an implementation of an abstract method and returning interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface IValue
{
    int Id { get;}
}

public class SpecificValue : IValue
{
    public int Id { get { return 3; } }
    public string Val { get; set; } 
}

public abstract class MustImplement
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<IValue> GetValues(int number);
}

public class SpecificClass : MustImplement
{
    public override IEnumerable<IValue> GetValues(int number)
    {
        var rv = new List<SpecificValue>();
        rv.Add(new SpecificValue()
        {Val = number + "Test"});
        return rv;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new SpecificClass();
        var values = test.GetValues(1).Single();
        Console.WriteLine(values.Id);
        //Console.WriteLine(values.Val); // This doesnt work

        var values2 = test.GetValues(1).Single() as SpecificValue;
        Console.WriteLine(values2.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(values2.Val); // This works but I dont want to have to cast. values2 is also potentially null now and that's annoying
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7tA12E

This is a contrived example to simplify for example. When using `SpecificClass` I want to get `SpecificValue` automatically without having to cast it.

The abstract class/interface is just there to force a contract. I don't want to actually get interfaces as a return, but what `GetValues()` returns isnt specific and depends on each implementation (as long as they obey the contract)

I attempted to rewrite it using generics so that you can do

`test.GetValues<SpecificValue>(1).Single()` but I still believe there is a way to return a SpecificValue without having to type SpecificValue in Main()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your abstract class as generic class like this:

```
public abstract class MustImplement<T> where T: IValue
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetValues(int number);
}

public class SpecificClass : MustImplement<SpecificValue>
{
    public override IEnumerable<SpecificValue> GetValues(int number)
    {
        var rv = new List<SpecificValue>();
        rv.Add(new SpecificValue()
        {Val = number + "Test"});
        return rv;
    }
}
```